# Add button doesnt work in dynamic frorm from wbraganca in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks, yii2-advanced-app, dynamicform

I am using **yii2 framework**, i tried to use **dynamic form** from **wbraganca**, but the **add button doesnt work** even when i put the **formId** in **ActiveForm::begin**, help me to solve this problem.

Check the code **_form in view:**

```
<div class="compra-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'id_utilizador')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'id_fornecedor')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Fornecedor::find()->all(), 'id_fornecedor', 'nome'),
        ['prompt'=>'Seleciona um Fornecedor']
); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'id_armazem')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Armazem::find()->all(), 'id_armazem', 'endereco'),
        ['prompt'=>'Seleciona um Armazem']
); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'data_compra')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'obs')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> Itens da Compra</h4></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                    'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                    'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                    'limit' => 4, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                    'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                    'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                    'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                    'model' => $modelsItem[0],
                    'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                    'formFields' => [
                        'id_item',
                        'unidade',
                    ],
                ]); ?>

        <div class="container-items">

            <?php foreach ($modelsItem as $i => $modelItem): ?>

                <div class="item panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Item</h3>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="col-sm-6">

                            <?= $form->field($modelItem, '[{$i}]id_item')->dropDownList(
                                    ArrayHelper::map(Item::find()->all(), 'id_item', 'nome'),
                                    ['prompt'=>'Seleciona um item']
                            ); ?>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">

                            <?= $form->field($modelItem, "[{$i}]unidade")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>



        <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but in line:
$form->field($modelItem, '[{$i}]id_item')->dropDownList(..
shouldn't id_item be written in double quote? (in order for $i to be printed)?

Comment: 'id_item' is my model's id, like 'unidade' is my model's attribute, i have changed the line ''$form->field($modelItem, '[{$i}]id_item')->dropDownList(..) ' to '$form->field($modelItem, "[{$i}]id_item")->textInput()' but the add button doesnt work yet.

Comment: this solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/41159047/7973949